# Display an image using two random arrays using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image

I'm trying to display an image using two arrays that will randomly select a number and suit type for a card game.

I want to concatenate the two arrays so that it will be able to load the image file and then display the file when loaded.

The files for the cards are saved for example like '2Clubs.png'

here's my code:
javascript

```
crand=Math.ceil(Math.random()*12);
crand1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*12);
crand2=Math.ceil(Math.random()*12);
srand=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
srand1=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
srand2=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

Hcrand=Math.ceil(Math.random()*12);
Hcrand1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*12);
Hcrand2=Math.ceil(Math.random()*12);
Hsrand=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
Hsrand1=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
Hsrand2=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

cards=new Array(13);
cards[0]='2';
cards[1]='3';
cards[2]='4';
cards[3]='5';
cards[4]='6';
cards[5]='7';
cards[6]='8';
cards[7]='9';
cards[8]='10';
cards[9]='Jack';
cards[10]='Queen';
cards[11]='King';
cards[12]='Ace';

suit=new Array(4);
suit[0]='Hearts';
suit[1]='Spades';
suit[2]='Clubs';
suit[3]='Diamonds';


img = document.getElementById('img1');
img.src=cards[crand]+suit[srand]+'.png';
```

HTML

```
<img id="img1" src="" width="100" height="100"></img>
```

File structure:

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry I've edited my post. so i want to use the two arrays to choose the image file like what i've tried to do with the two lines at the bottom of the javascript code then display it in the HTML code.

Comment: do you know that you can declare array as `arr = [1,2,3]` ? and do you know that `img` is a self closing tag?

Comment: @AStephens, why do you want to concatenate the two arrays? Have a look at my answer

Comment: for example when two elements in each array has been selected it should choose a a card number and a card suit e.g. 4Clubs which will then be the same as what the files are saved as so that i can display them on the screen. does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: No need to concatenate the two arrays. What you did is fine: randomly selected a value and a color, then concatenate the two: this gives you the card name. That you can then call by changing the `src` of your image.

---

You have to declare your variables with `let`. For the purpose of this little program, I have created a `randomInt()` function that randomly returns an integer between 0 and the value given as argument.

```js
function randomInt(max) {
  let min = 0;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

let crand = randomInt(12);
let srand = randomInt(3);

let cards = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace'];
let suit = ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds'];


let img = document.getElementById('img1');
img.src = cards[crand] + suit[srand] + '.png';

console.log(cards[crand] + suit[srand] + '.png')
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="" width="100" height="100">
```

Assuming you have your images **in the same directory** as the HTML page. If not just navigate by using a prefix `../` to get out of the current directory, etc...

Comment: I've just given this a try and its still just displaying a broken image

Comment: @Ivan he's getting broken image because `randomInt` for `crand` and `srand` is passed 4 and 13 limits instead of 13 and 4 respectively. Easy to catch, but looks like OP is just after copy-pasting solution without bothering much.

Comment: `crand` and `srand` were switched: so it was looking for an index that didn't exist: look at my edited code. It works now.

Comment: i've added a image of my directory in my original post. I'm still not sure as to why this isnt working.  

I've tested the images on their own and they load fine its just when trying to get random cards to appear

Comment: @Ivan there is a bug where it randomly tries to access `undefinedClubs.png`

Comment: Yeah, it's doing the same as it was before.

Comment: @Ivan because arrays are 0 based it should be `let crand = randomInt(12);` not `let crand = randomInt(13);`, it wont let me edit it due to it saying i need 6 or more character changes

Comment: My apologies the issue was the argument given to `randomInt()`: the function returns a value between 0 and the argument both included. You have 13 card values so you need to call it with `randomInt(12)` because the array starts at `0`.

Comment: @AStephens if you find this answer helpful consider upvoting/accepting this for future users